# order of execution of axios instance call and the interceptors code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, httprequest, interceptor

I'm using Axios and interceptors in my React Native project to handle session authorization and to call the refresh token. I want to understand the order of execution during an API call. Should I start with the code inside the interceptor or with the axiosInstance, and then catch the response? Below is the timeline of my code execution :

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create();
interceptors(axiosInstance);

function apiFetcher<T>(request: RequestType): Promise<T> {

    updateStore({ isFetching: true })
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // @ts-ignore
        axiosInstance({
            method: request.method,
            url: request.url,
            timeout: 20000,
            ...(request.responseType && { responseType: request.responseType }),
            headers: {
                ...request.headers,
                //    ...(!request?.isPublic && { Authorization: "Bearer " + token, }),
                'Accept-Language': currentLanguage,
            },
            data: request.payload,
        })
            .then((response: any) => {

                updateStore({ isFetching: false })
                resolve(response.data);
            })
            .catch(async (error: AxiosError) => {
                updateStore({ isFetching: false })

         
                reject(errorMessage);
            });
    });
}
```

thanks :)

I tried the code provided above, and I would appreciate your feedback on the order of execution. If you have any suggestions, I would be grateful to hear them. Additionally, if someone could explain how interceptors work, it would be helpful. Thank you